# Spring Boot - Use Application Listener

Tags: java, spring-boot

After starting my spring boot application I want to start an customer process like creating required folders, files, etc. For that I'm using `ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>`. This works like expected. But I'm building my spring application context with `SpringApplicationBuilder`. Every child notifies that the application is started correctly. So my customer post-process startes even more than one time.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = {StorageProperties.class})
@EnableAsync
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplicationBuilder parentBuilder
            = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);

    parentBuilder.child(Config1.class)
            .properties("server.port:1443")
            ...
            .run(args);
    parentBuilder.child(Config2.class)
            .properties("server.port:2443")
            ...
            .run(args);
  }
}
```

My first idea was, that I can create manuelly a new Bean with **@Bean** in Config1 for my Event-Listener. But I was not able to overhand the configuration file StorageProperties.class, which is necessary for this class.

Because the Listener has an constructor based dependency injection:

```
private final Path mPathTo;
public AfterStart(StorageProperties prop) {
    this.mPathTo = Paths.get(prob.getPath());
}
```

How can I be able to start the listener just once per start?

Comment: I am not sure that makes sense that `ApplicationReadyEvent` is fired multiple times. Can you create a small sample that demonstrates that behaviour and create an issue in our tracker please?

Comment: I hoped this sample will be enough to make the demonstration. What is missing for the small sample demonstration? Do you need a working small application? (Just ask to make it right)

Comment: Issue done with a small demonstration: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8899

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everyone who is interested in this question. This solution worked for me:

```
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent e) {
    if (e.getApplicationContext().getParent == null) {
        System.out.println("******************************");
        System.out.println("Post-process begins.");
        System.out.println("******************************");      
    }
}
```

Comment: I recently ran into this issue as well. But the getParent() == null does not work for me since it's never null. The resolution from the spring boot issue: make the listener context aware and compare the context of the readyevent with the context from the listener is saver to use.